# IOS testFlight invitation email "This message has no text content"

Tags: ios, testflight

I am using testFlight to invite internal users. All other users(like gmail) works well except the iCloud email one. Internal test user can get the email, but without a text body like with **Start testing** button.

Like below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried viewing it in a mail application rather than in browser?

Comment: @JordanSmith I guess it's flash issue or network issue maybe. I tried it again after few hours, it works finally. Thank you!